# Dynamically add (pre-defined) instance method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, instance-methods

I see how to dynamically add a method to an instance in Ruby with `def [instance].[methodname]; [...]; end`.

However, I'm interested in attaching a method that exists in another location to a given instance. e.g.

```
def my_meth
  puts self.foo
end

class MyCls
  attr_accessor :foo
end

my_obj = MyCls.new
my_obj.my_meth
```

How could I simply attach `my_meth` to `my_obj` so that the method call in the final line of the foregoing code would work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`include`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M000440) or [`extend`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001002) to add a module to your class, eg. `extend`:

```
module Foo
  def my_meth
    puts self.foo
  end
end

class MyCls
  attr_accessor :foo
end

my_obj = MyCls.new
my_obj.extend(Foo)
my_obj.foo = "hello"
my_obj.my_meth
```

Unless you have a need to mix-in a module on the fly like this it's generally better to `include` your module like so:

```
class MyCls
   include Foo
   attr_accessor :foo
end
```